# Spectral theorem - what does the orthogonal matrix look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

> Spectral theorem:
>
> Let $A$ be a real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. Then there exists a
> real orthogonal matrix $P$ with $B=P^{-1}AP$ diagonal.

My lecture notes only give a proof for the case where there are $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

Proof outline in this case (see [here](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emaskal/MA106NotesMaclaganTesta.pdf)):

We know that a real symmetric matrix has only real eigenvalues, so there are $n$ distinct real eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$. Let $v_1,..,v_n$ be the corresponding eigenvalues, then we also know that $v_i \cdot v_j$ for $i \neq j$ and $v_i \cdot v_i>0$, so we can normalize them. Thus, we may assume $v_i \cdot v_i=1$ such that $v_1,...,v_n$ forms an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ since the set is linearly independent. It follows that the matrix $P$ with columns $v_1,...,v_n$ is orthogonal. It is also easy so see that $B=P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal with entries $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ on its diagonal.

So in this case the matrix $B$ consists of eigenvalues of $A$ and the columns of matrix $P$ are the corresponding eigenvectors.

Now I also looked up a [proof](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Efreiwald/309orthogdiag.pdf) for the general case which is done by induction. Basically, we just use one eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and then build an orthonormal basis including the corresponding eigenvalue $v_1$. Then we show that $P^(-1)AP$ is symmetric and has $(\lambda_1,0,...,0)^T$ as its first column/row and note that we can break this matrix into parts and use the induction assumption to finish the proof.

Now my question is:

How do we know that the diagonal matrix still consists of the eigenvalues of $A$. Why does the orthonormal basis constructed consist of eigenvectors as in the case of $n$ distinct eigenvalues? I feel like this cannot be the case because there are not enough eigenvectors since some eigenvalues might appear more than once. Or are there multiple different unit eigenvalues that correspond to one eigenvalue if it has a multiplicity larger than $1$?

Could someone clarify this for me, please? Thanks a lot for any help and suggestions.

Edit: Removed unimportant parts and clarified what the exact question is.

Comment: So you think that if there is an n by n matrix and one of its eigenvalues (say $\lambda_1$) is repeated (say twice), then matrix P will fall short of 1 eigenvector and hence matrix A won't be diagonalizable? Think about null space of $A-\lambda I$. Even if $\lambda $ is repeated (say, twice), null space ($A-\lambda I$) might be of dimension 2, so you may have full set of eigenvectors.

Comment: I first thought that it cannot be true that the orthonormal basis or in other words the columns of $P$ only consist of eigenvectors if some eigenvalues are repeated. But after I thought about it some more I think that it may still be true. Basically the eigenvalues tell me for which value of $\lambda$ the system $A-\lambda I=0$ has infinitely many solutions. In that case the set of solutions could be a line or a plane, etc. depending on how many free variables we have. Is this correct?

Comment: My problem is not that I think that such a matrix won't be diagonalizable. I mean the proof clearly establishes this. My main question is why the matrix $D$ has the eigenvalues of $A$ on its diagonal and why the matrix $P$ consist of eigenvectors of $A$. This is clear to me in the proof for the case of $n$ distinct eigenvalues, but not in the general case.

Comment: Just a little algebraic manipulation does the trick. I'll denote B by D (diagonal). Note that, PD=AP. $[p_1, p_2, ... ,p_n] D=A[p_1, p_2,...,p_n]$ compare both sides. Let the diagonals of D be $d_1,d_2...d_n$. Hence, $p_i d_i=Ap_i$. Now use definition of eigenvectors/eigenvalues. It follows that $p_i$ is eigenvector of A and $d_i$ is the corresponding eigenvector. Pardon the use of commas to separate columns of matrix P.

Comment: Ok, I got it now think. Thanks a lot! If you want to write this as a short answer I will accept it.